# Share image/text through WhatsApp in an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to share images, text or whatever you want through Whatsapp in a iOS app? I'm searching on google but I only found results talking about Android implementations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<s>No this is not possible, whatsapp does not have any public API you can use.</s>

**Please note that this answer is correct for 2011 when there was no API for WhatsApp.**

Now there is an api available for interacting with WhatsApp: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

The Objective-C call to open one of these URLs is as follows:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

Comment: Is there any character limit?

Answer (score 133):

Is now possible in this way:

**Send Text - Obj-C**

```
NSString * msg = @"YOUR MSG";
NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",msg];
NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
} else {
    // Cannot open whatsapp
}
```

**Send Text - Swift**

```
let msg = "YOUR MSG"
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?text=\(msg)"
if let urlString = urlWhats.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()) {
    if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsappURL)
        } else {
            // Cannot open whatsapp
        }
    }
}
```

**Send Image - Obj-C**

**-- in .h file**

```
<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>

@property (retain) UIDocumentInteractionController * documentInteractionController;
```

**-- in .m file**

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){

    UIImage     * iconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR IMAGE"];
    NSString    * savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

    _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
    _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

    [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];


} else {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

**Send Image - Swift**

```
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://app"
if let urlString = urlWhats.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()) {
    if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {

        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {

            if let image = UIImage(named: "image") {
                if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
                    let tempFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai")
                    do {
                        try imageData.writeToURL(tempFile, options: .DataWritingAtomic)
                        self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: tempFile)
                        self.documentInteractionController.UTI = "net.whatsapp.image"
                        self.documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            // Cannot open whatsapp
        }
    }
}
```

> Because a new security feature of iOS 9, you need add this lines on
>   **.plist** file:
>
> ```
> <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
>  <array>
>   <string>whatsapp</string>
>  </array>
> ```
>
> More information about url sheme: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-703/

I did not find a single solution for both.
More information on http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

I made a small project to help some.
https://github.com/salesawagner/SharingWhatsApp

Comment: can text be sent to specific number via whatsapp? means no need to pick contact from whats app contact list ?

Comment: You need to have "ID Address Book" to associate with a contact, simply add the parameter "abid = <ID-ADDRESS-BOOK>". I do not know to send directly to the phone number, but I'm looking for a solution.
The link has a better explanation. http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: The whole "if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageCompartilhar)]) {" seems to be redundant. Other than this it works,

Comment: @vaiden, you're right about the "if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector: @ selector (imageCompartilhar)]) {" I put because I get the image of my delegate. something like "UIImage * iconImage = [_delegate imageCompartilhar];"

Answer (score 24):

It is now possible. Have not tried yet though.

The latest [release notes for whatsapp](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013) indicate that you can through the share extension:

WhatsApp accepts the following types of content:

- text (UTI: public.plain-text)
- photos (UTI: public.image)
- videos (UTI: public.movie)
- audio notes and music files (UTI: public.audio)
- PDF documents (UTI: com.adobe.pdf)
- contact cards (UTI: public.vcard)
- web URLs (UTI: public.url)

Comment: The above link does not allow for sharing of media to Whatsapp without displaying the menu. You must always show the document controller's menu before going to Whatsapp, which is a pain in the ass.

Comment: PDF documents (UTI: com.adobe.pdf) -> has problems while sharing. If I create pdf on the code, store it on documentdirectory and try to share it on whatsapp, it fails. I think whatsapp wants a pdf file that has a type of Adobe pdf i.e. has UTI com.adobe.pdf only

Answer (score 8):

This is the correct code for share link to whats app users.

```
NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://video...bla..bla.."];
url =    (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef) url, NULL,CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

  NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",url];
NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWhats];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
} else {
    // can not share with whats app
}
```

Answer (score 7):

***Simple code and Sample code ;-)***

## Note:- You can only share text or image, both sharing together in whatsApp is not working from whatsApp side

```
 /*
    //Share text
    NSString *textToShare = @"Enter your text to be shared";
    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare];
    
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
     */
    
    //Share Image
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images"];
    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[image];
    
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 4 - Works fine

delclare

```
var documentInteractionController:UIDocumentInteractionController!

func sharePicture() {
    let urlWhats = "whatsapp://app"
    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {

            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {

                let imgURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                let fileName = "yourImageName.jpg"
                let fileURL = imgURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path) {
                    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) {
                        let tempFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Documents/yourImageName.jpg")
                        do {
                            try imageData.write(to: tempFile!, options: .atomicWrite)
                            self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tempFile!)
                            self.documentInteractionController.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
                            self.documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Cannot open whatsapp
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to edit the .plist with the following lines

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>
```

Enjoy!!!

Comment: This doesn't open whatsapp directly, this opens the document interaction view. Any way to open directly whatsapp?

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 version of Wagner Sales' answer:

```
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://app"
if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
  if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {

      if let image = UIImage(named: "image") {
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
          let tempFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai")
          do {
            try imageData.write(to: tempFile!, options: .atomic)

            self.documentIC = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tempFile!)
            self.documentIC.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
            self.documentIC.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)
          }
          catch {
            print(error)
          }
        }
      }

    } else {
      // Cannot open whatsapp
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 4

```
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://app"
        if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed) {

            if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {

                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {

                        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
                            let tempFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai")!
                            do {
                                try imageData.write(to: tempFile, options: .atomic)
                                self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tempFile)
                                self.documentController.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
                                self.documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }

                } else {
                    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "MessageAletTitleText".localized, message: "AppNotFoundToShare".localized, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OKButtonText".localized, style: .default))
                    present(ac, animated: true)

                    print("Whatsapp isn't installed ")

                    // Cannot open whatsapp
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp provides two ways for your iPhone app to interact with WhatsApp:

- Through a custom URL scheme
- Through the iOS Document Interaction API

For more information Visit [this link](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible :

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSString *textToShare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n",_model.title];
    NSString *SchoolName= [[AppUtility sharedUtilityInstance]getAppConfigInfoByKey:@"SchoolName" SecondKeyorNil:Nil];
    [arr addObject:textToShare];
    [arr addObject:URL];
    [arr addObject:_model.body];
    [arr addObject:SchoolName];
    TTOpenInAppActivity *openInAppActivity = [[TTOpenInAppActivity alloc] initWithView:_parentController.view andRect:((UIButton *)sender).frame];

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:arr applicationActivities:@[openInAppActivity]];

    // Store reference to superview (UIActionSheet) to allow dismissal
    openInAppActivity.superViewController = activityViewController;
    // Show UIActivityViewController
    [_parentController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3** version for sending text:

```
func shareByWhatsapp(msg:String){
        let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?text=\(msg)"
        if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
            if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL as URL)
                } else {

                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Whatsapp not found", comment: "Error message"),
                                                  message: NSLocalizedString("Could not found a installed app 'Whatsapp' to proceed with sharing.", comment: "Error description"),
                                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: "Alert button"), style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
                    }))

                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
                    // Cannot open whatsapp
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Also, you need to add `whatsapp` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your `Info.plist`

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *shareText = @"http:www.google.com";
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[shareText];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

if (isIphone)
{
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else {
    UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc]         initWithContentViewController:activityVC];
    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You need to add some explanation. Why do you think this code works? How is it different from earlier answers?