# Share video on whatsapp - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ios7.1, whatsapp

On iOS 7.1.1, I can share image by this code on Whatsapp..

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){

        UIImage     * iconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
        NSString    * savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

        self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
        self.docController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
        self.docController.delegate = self;
        //[self.docController setAnnotation:@{@"WhatsappCaption" : @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/epic-ar/id535122470?ls=1&mt=8"}];

        [self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view animated: YES];

}
```

But I want to share video too, I follow tutorial on [Wahtsapp tutorial](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)

But How can be the code of video path ?

I mean, What is the alternative object of UIImage object to display video ?

Also, can I share "Link" ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while, but I put the pieces together

references: [Share image/text through WhatsApp in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354417/share-image-text-through-whatsapp-in-an-ios-app)
    // http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

```
//---NEXT LINE OF CODE IS OPTIONAL AND NOT RECOMMENDED, BUT YOU CAN USE IT TO TEST TO SEE IF THEY HAVE THE WHATSAPP INSTALLED
//    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){

    NSString    * savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wam"];

    savePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];


    _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
    _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.movie";
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = (id)self;

    [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];
```

This is only to answer your main question: Share video on whatsapp

Comment: Thank you it worked, that helped me, I tried it before but failed, Also I use now mp4.

Comment: I also forgot to mention since this is using Document interaction, this code will open any app that can open that file. Install some apps that can open a video and see what happens. You will notice that the device will give you an option as to which app to open it with. That's why I said optional, but not recommended to use that line of code if canOpenURL because WhatsApp is not going to be the only app that allows this.

Comment: How can we do the exact same thing but with video saved in Document directory and not added by the developer in the app bundle ?
'''savePath = self.getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Movie.m4v")'''
It does not work to send video in WhatsApp if I changed savePath by that code