# Whatsapp sharing text and image is not working in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

If sending text to WhatsApp:

```
NSString *msg = @"Some Text";
NSString *urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",msg];
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
} else {
  UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
}
```

If sending image to WhatsApp:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){

   UIImage* iconImage = [self captureScreen];// this will return a image
   NSString* savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

   [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

   _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
   _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
   _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

   [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];
} else {
   UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
}
```

Whatsapp is opened without any text for text sharing and image is also not getting shared. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354417/share-image-text-through-whatsapp-in-an-ios-app look at this

Comment: I have tried the same but its not working

Comment: what is error coming

Comment: text is working but for image app is getting crashed

Comment: LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called

Answer (score 2):

Did you add "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" to you plist?

1. Go to your project/Supporting Files/YourProjectName-Info.plist in
   XCode project Explorer.
2. Add a new key-value pair. Key :
   LSApplicationQueriesSchemes Type : Array Add a new string item
   "whatsapp"

Please try this and let me know if it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

## note:- You can only share text or image, both sharing together in whatsApp is not working from whatsApp side

```
 /*
    //Share text
    NSString *textToShare = @"Enter your text to be shared";
    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare];
    
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
     */
    
    //Share Image
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images"];
    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[image];
    
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```