# How to share video on whatsapp in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, whatsapp

I want to share video on **whatsapp** but I have savePath nil error.

I used this code:

```
NSString    * savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wam"];
savePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
_documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
_documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.movie";
_documentInteractionController.delegate = (id)self;
[_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];
```

Where is my error?

Comment: Is your video added to the project bundle or you want to share camera roll video ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Swift version:

```
func sendVideo(videoName: String, senderView: UIView) {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(videoName, ofType:"m4v")! 
    let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)! 

    docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileUrl) 
    docController.UTI = "net.whatsapp.movie"
    docController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: senderView, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you casted fileUrl as NSURL when it was already an NSURL. You seem to be creating 'data' but not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

references: [Share image/text through WhatsApp in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354417/share-image-text-through-whatsapp-in-an-ios-app) // http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

```
//---NEXT LINE OF CODE IS OPTIONAL AND NOT RECOMMENDED, BUT YOU CAN USE IT TO TEST TO SEE IF THEY HAVE THE WHATSAPP INSTALLED
//    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){
NSString    * savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wam"];

savePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];


_documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
_documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.movie";
_documentInteractionController.delegate = (id)self;

[_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];
```