# Share text and image on whatsapp using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

With the latest version of whatsapp, I cannot share both text and image at the same time.

I tried the below code:

```
let image:UIImage = UIImage(named:"ImageName")
objectsToShare = [image,"textToShare"]
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
```

With this code I am able to share only the text, but the other sharing apps(such as SMS, etc) are able to share both text and image.

Comment: you can't share both in whatsapp

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920041/send-image-and-text-with-whatsapp

Comment: Can't post both. Choose any one. check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920041/send-image-and-text-with-whatsapp  And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354417/share-image-text-through-whatsapp-in-an-ios-app?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Any other way we can share like using any whatsapp API ?

Comment: Is your text really long? If you're fine with keeping the text short, I can post an answer explaining how to overlay the image with text.