# "This item cannot be shared. Please select a different item." WhatsApp iOS share extension failure message

Tags: ios, iphone, whatsapp, ios8-share-extension

***This bug is fixed by WhatsApp team on 23rd May, 2016 (build no. 2.16.4).***

Unable to share NSString object using `UIActivityViewController` to WhatsApp.

I tried to share using below code. But once contact is selected from the list, it shows an alert displaying "`This item cannot be shared. Please select a different item.`"

**CODE**

```
NSString *shareText = @"Temp text to share";
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[shareText];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
```

I am facing this problem after updating WhatsApp to version 2.16.2

Comment: Did you figure it out ? Because even I  am facing the same problem, It used to work properly till the last update of Whats App , but now its not !

Comment: Same problem here. It's really frustrating.

Comment: Nope. Sent a mail to whatsapp support team about this product issue. Not a reply since 4 days. No idea what to do but for temporary fix i just allow sharing link now.

Comment: Sure it's because of whatsapp and their native support for ActivityViewController?

Comment: After playing a lil bit it seems whatsapp won't allow you to share directly text. But it allows you to share urls, videos, images, etc. So (at least in our case) we were sharing Text with embedded url and we replaced it to:
`@[NSURL(***), "share Text"];`  
so that whatsapp only takes the url but the rest of apps take the text too.

Comment: After my testing I have to thank @EliKohen for the info. Hope this changes in the future :)

Comment: Having the same issue any recent update on this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Received a response from WhatsApp team

> ### - WhatsApp Support -
>
> Hi,
>
> Sorry for the delay! We have received many emails recently, and we do
> our best to answer them all. Thank you for your patience.
>
> Thank you for informing us about the issue; it will be fixed in a
> future version of WhatsApp. Unfortunately, we cannot comment on any
> future timelines, sorry. Thank you for your continued patience and
> support of WhatsApp.
>
> Cheers,  Hans

So, they acknowledge the bug and will fix this in the next release.

**Possible Workarounds =>**

- Till then one can use UrlSchemes to share plaintext+url. Follow
  [Spydy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36622573/1137288).

  **OR**
- One can create subclass of UIActivity with
  activityCategory as UIActivityCategoryShare with whatsapp icon. Then
  when user selects it, will use urlschemes to share text. For this use [JBWhatsAppActivity](https://github.com/jberlana/JBWhatsAppActivity)

  **OR**
- Just share NSUrl object for sharing url. Once the fix is done you can revert to sharing plain text and url.

Comment: if i use JBWhatsAppActivity how to remove original WhatsApp in first lane?

Comment: did u try removing the original whatsapp activity by knowing its ActivityType String and providing it in excludedActivityTypes.

Comment: how? there is no UIActivityType for WhatsApp in UIActivity.h

Answer (score 9):

You might wanna try sharing the local URL of the item you're trying to share. For example, if you'd like to share a pdf, don't try to share it's NSData or Data object, WhatsApp still does show that error for that. Instead, if you share the local URL of it, WhatsApp recognizes it and shares it well.

I must note that many apps including native Mail, Gmail, Slack, GDrive etc. do recognize the pdf if you try to share the Data object.

For example:

After downloading a PDF, bind its URL into a variable called fileURL:

```
var fileURL = URL(string: url)
    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("AWESOME_PDF.pdf")
        return (fileURL!, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }
```

Then you can simply share the fileURL instead:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(            
      activityItems: [fileURL!],
      applicationActivities: nil
)
```

WhatsApp will recognize the PDF.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can send the pdf through WhatsApp with this solution. But from other iOS devices that pdf is opening but not from the Android. Any idea, why?

Answer (score 8):

have faced same issue after updating whatsapp. Even you press "**cancel**" on whatsapp still completion block shows success.
 i have resolved it by using "**WFActivitySpecificItemProvider**" and "**WFActivitySpecificItemProvider**"when sharing on whatsapp then dissmiss activityViewController and share via ur. You can pull  **WFActivitySpecificItemProvider**, **activityViewController** classes from https://github.com/wileywimberly/WFActivitySpecificItemProvider

here is my code

```
- (void)share{

NSString *defaultMessage = @"your message may contain url";

// Use a dictionary
WFActivitySpecificItemProvider *provider1 =
[[WFActivitySpecificItemProvider alloc]
 initWithPlaceholderItem:@""
 items:@{
         WFActivitySpecificItemProviderTypeDefault : defaultMessage,
         UIActivityTypePostToFacebook : defaultMessage,
         UIActivityTypeMail : defaultMessage,
         UIActivityTypeMessage : defaultMessage,
         @"com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension":defaultMessage,
         UIActivityTypePostToTwitter : defaultMessage

         }];


// Use a block
WFActivitySpecificItemProvider *provider2 =
[[WFActivitySpecificItemProvider alloc]
 initWithPlaceholderItem:@""
 block:^(NSString *activityType){

     if ([activityType isEqualToString:@"net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension"]) {


         [avc dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

         dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



             NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",defaultMessage];
             NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];


         });
     }

     return defaultMessage;
 }];


avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
       initWithActivityItems:@[provider1, provider2]
       applicationActivities:nil];

[avc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[avc setValue:sharingHeader forKey:@"subject"];

[avc setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {

    if (activityType) {


        NSLog(@"activity: %@ completed: %@",activityType,completed ? @"YES" : @"NO");


    } else {


        NSLog(@"No activity was selected. (Cancel)");
    }

}];

[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Your case may be different, in my case i have to show one share button for all kinds of sharing apps installed in my phone. so above code works for my case.

Comment: I am thinking along same lines. I will create subclass of UIActivity with activityCategory as UIActivityCategoryShare with whatsapp icon. Then when user selects it, will use urlschemes to share text. But i will wait for sometime till i get a reply from whatsapp product team.

Comment: Please let me know the Whatsapp team says. Thanks

Comment: We are facing the same issue here, so let us know once you receive a reply from Whatsapp

Answer (score 2):

WhatsApp has fixed this bug in the their update dated 23rd May, 2016 (build no. 2.16.4).

It hasn't been reported by official sources, but I have tested it in my code - works fine.

Comment: There are still issues with this, if you use 1Password for example and share a password from your vault with WhatsApp the error message will appear when you select a person to sent it to.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of whatsapp, Now we can not share both text and URL at the same time.

I tried the below code

```
NSArray *activityItems= @[someText,[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

With this code i am able to share only the URL link, the whatsApp filtered out the "someText" text.

but the other share apps(SMS etc) able to share both text and url.

hope WhatsApp fixes this issue soon.

Comment: do u really think this answers it while other answers can't.  Please readout other answers before posting another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem with a custom [UIActivityItemSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemsource) where I was passing back `kUTTypeData` that most providers understand for the `dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType` delegate method instead of `kUTTypeText`.  Simple case overrides fixed the issue in my case. Just another reason the error above could be popping if anyone sees it.

```
open func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
    switch activityType {
    case UIActivityType(rawValue: "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension"):
        return kUTTypeText as String
    default:
        return kUTTypeData as String
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about your question... Do you want just send text by whatsapp? If yes, you don't need use **UIActivityViewController**. Just use **urlschemes**.

Something like that:

```
NSString *string = @"whatsapp://send?text=<YOUR MESSAGE>";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: ];
```

You also can check if the user have whatsapp installed

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: url]) {
   // wahtsapp installed
} else {
   // whatsapp not installed
}
```

Look this question:
[Share image/text through WhatsApp in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354417/share-image-text-through-whatsapp-in-an-ios-app/20601051#20601051)

Comment: I know this. But i am not looking to use url schemes. Because its three taps away from sharing and looks lengthy process. I am more worried why WhatsApp native share extension is not working the way it used to work before.
Please try it once and let me know if its working for you. Previously i used to share plane text NSString object which contains custom message and link. Now it doesn't even support plain text messages.

Comment: Hummmm... Interesting. I'll look for about  WhatsApp native share extension.

Comment: Your code just prove this url which given as string object can assign NSURL  . It's not related about Whatsapp..

Comment: It's an way to send whatsapp msg... Look the url scheme. @InnaKamoze

Comment: That's not solving a problem, you need to add a row in to plist as an array "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" and insert a row as  string  "whatsapp" instead URL Scheme works.

Comment: Just adding  "whatsapp" to  "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" solved my problem of sharing text.