# (This Item Cannot Be Shared, Please Select a Different Item) Sharing A Simple Text To Whats App Is Not Working Since Updated To iOS 9.3 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, whatsapp, share-extension

This code used to work fine till the last update of XCode 7.3 and IOS 9.3, I tried searching over the internet but got nothing, So if anyone can help me out here would be a great help. Thank You

The code I am using to share the text in Swift is this:-

```
let objectsToShare = [TextToShare]
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

//New Excluded Activities Code
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone) {
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else { //if iPad
// Change Rect to position Popover
let popoverCntlr = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: activityVC)
popoverCntlr.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0), inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)

}
```

The console show this error:-

```
plugin net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension interrupted
plugin net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension invalidated
```

And while sharing on Whats App shows this:

[image: Screenshot from mobile]

Comment: have you tried sharing with From another app to WhatsApp ? maybe its Whatsapp issue and not yours?

Comment: Nope I didnt tried sharing from another app but even I was thinking the same , May be the issue is from whats app only

Comment: same issue for whats app in Objective-C ... any solution ?

Comment: Still No Luck, May be its from whats app

Comment: its whatsApp bug....you can WhatsApp Support  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603921/this-item-cannot-be-shared-please-select-a-different-item-whatsapp-ios-share

Comment: getting the same issue any recent update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this was an issue from WhatsApp's side. And it's now fixed with the latest update. I just confirmed it's working with my app. So, just update WhatsApp and it should work.