# Share String + Image through WhatsApp in an iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

Share string + image through WhatsApp in iOS 9 + Xcode 7.3, getting error.
iOS 8 working perfectly.
Code :

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePrint,
                                   UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                   UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [activityController setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test msg"] forKey:@"subject"];

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `iOS 9`, you need add this lines on projects `.plist` file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>
```

Check after adding this in `.plist`.

Comment: @Ronak Chaniyara i also try that but it is not working.

Comment: check answer here may it help [http://stackoverflow.com/a/36622573/5575752](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36622573/5575752)

Comment: I also used this one, but it works on iOS 8, not working iOS 9!

Comment: @Mahipalsinh than what you try for iOS9 ?

Comment: @iPhoneDev Yes, when i am testing in iOS 9, that time give me alert like this.But, I solve this issue using below code

Answer (score 0):

I solved issued using this code :

```
- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
{
    return @"";
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController )activityViewController itemsForActivityType:(NSString )activityType
{

    if ([activityType isEqualToString:@"net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension"]) {

        NSString *strShare = @“Test string”;

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",strShare];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];

        return @"";

    }
    else
    {
        return  sharingItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: how to call this method on button click ?

Comment: This two are Datasource method of UIActivityItemSource. So, it call automatically . Please refer this URL : http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/

Comment: but i want call on button than where i set delegate or method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add image url, because sharing image is not possible.
Add image url like this

```
NSArray *arrData = @[@"Post Title", @"imageURL"];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:arrData applicationActivities:nil];
NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```