# Sharing does not work with Whatsapp and Facebook - swift project

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, share, whatsapp

I'm developing an iOS application using swift and firebase.

I'm trying to add sharing ability, where the user can share some information from firebase to social networkings apps.

Here's the button I added:

```
     @IBAction func text2share(sender: AnyObject) {
    let text2share = "Check out this ✨ \r\n Business Name:  \(self.BusinessNameL.text!)  \r\n Phone: \(self.PhoneNumberTV.text!) \r\n Category: \(self.CategoryL.text!) \r\n Website: \(self.Website1TV.text!) \r\n in Business Wallet app "
    let objects2Share = [text2share]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objects2Share, applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I tried it, it worked for all social networks apps except for whatsapp and Facebook!

*Here's the error I got when I try to share it to whatsapp:
[image]

*Here's What I got when I share to Facebook:
[image]
And the link is empty!

Is there anybody know how can I solve this?
And why this happens?

Comment: It's because of the emoji's that you are using. You can try to use the unicode values of the emoji as string.

Comment: @ Eric D I replace it.

Comment: @ Umar Farooque I tried to add U+1F60D instead of this emoji  , and remove all of the other emojis, it gave same result!

Comment: @ Umar Farooque I tried to remove all of the emojis, it did not work as well!

Comment: wait let me check.

Comment: What link is “empty”? I don’t see you specifying a link in the code shown.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't set any initial text when sharing to Facebook. You can only provide a link.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug on whatsapp.

Check this 
[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603921/this-item-cannot-be-shared-please-select-a-different-item-whatsapp-ios-share). It discusses the same. It seems like a very recent bug as earlier the same methods used to work. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36856840/2570153) by santhu for possible workaround or wait since they have admitted to resolve the bug.

if you try this code, you can share just the URL which I was talking about.

```
    let textToShare = "Check out this  Business Name"
    let appURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")! as NSURL
    let objectsToShare = [textToShare, appURL]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    //New Excluded Activities Code
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to share your text via facebook  add excludeActivities

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objects2Share, applicationActivities: nil)

let excludeActivities = [UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail]

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities  
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This code has hide the Facebook from sharing option?!!