# Is it possible in iOS send text through WhatsApp to specific contact number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

Is it possible send a text through WhatsApp to a specific contact number?

I saw this question: [Share image/text through WhatsApp in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354417/share-image-text-through-whatsapp-in-an-ios-app) but it's too old and there is no answer about send to a specific contact.

I also know about this link: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Thanks!

Comment: Our back end developer used to do that using an un-offical api. but that was two years ago. Those backend developers used to have a private google chat group and share their finding. but, that before WhatsApp got bought by Facebook. I dont know wht is the case now.

Answer (score 0):

sending a whatsapp message to a particular contact:

```
    NSURL *whatsappLink = [NSURL URLWithString: @"whatsapp://send?phone=+913932143213&text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappLink]){
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    }
```