# Image share only on whatsapp in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

I want to share image only on whatsapp, but the code I use, shows other online share platform i.e. messenger & email.

Code I used:

```
    func share(shareText:String?,shareImage:UIImage?){

    var objectsToShare = [AnyObject]()

    if let shareTextObj = shareText{
        objectsToShare.append(shareTextObj as AnyObject)
    }

    if let shareImageObj = shareImage{
        objectsToShare.append(shareImageObj)
    }

    if shareText != nil || shareImage != nil{
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        print("There is nothing to share")
    }
}
```

and to share

```
    let imageToShare = UIImage(named: "05")
    share(shareText: "", shareImage: imageToShare)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not hide all the option that are showing in the `UIActivityViewController` because it depends on the content you are sharing and also installed app in your device, but you can hide most of it like all default options like this way:

```
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityType.assignToContact,
        UIActivityType.print,
        UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
        UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivityType.openInIBooks,
        UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension"), 
        UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension"),
    ]

    present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

### OR

If you want to share only in whatapp so here is the way to do it. please refer below url:

[Share image/text through WhatsApp in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354417/share-image-text-through-whatsapp-in-an-ios-app)

Comment: Mr. Patrick thanks for reply , but direct whatsapp link is used to share only text not images . any other way to do this ?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354417/share-image-text-through-whatsapp-in-an-ios-app#answer-40433392

Answer (score 2):

By adding some extra line to Mr. Patricks code I reduce the extra online sharing option that satified my need , If any one facing the same problem for those I want share that. I remove all other sharing option except WhatsApp using below code and it just shows WhatsApp and more option to share on screen  . Thanks

```
 func shareImg(){

    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityType.postToTwitter,
        UIActivityType.postToWeibo,
        UIActivityType.message,
        UIActivityType.mail,
        UIActivityType.print,
        UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard,
        UIActivityType.assignToContact,
        UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
        UIActivityType.postToFlickr,
        UIActivityType.postToVimeo,
        UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,
        UIActivityType.airDrop
    ]
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
        if !completed {

            print("User canceled")
            self.shareItems.removeAll()
            return
        }

        print("share successfully")

      }
  }
```