# Not able to share pdf via whatsapp

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm having an html data that is being converted to pdf. Now I want to share that pdf via whatsapp. I tried to achieve it like so...

```
  let pdfData = generatePDF(from: self.appDelegate.HTMLContent)

  let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:  [pdfData], applicationActivities: nil)

self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But when I select the recipient for sending, get the message `This item cannot be shared. Please select a different item` But the sharing can be done via message app. The problem is with whatsapp.

Did refer this link also..[Share PDF through WhatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022906/share-pdf-through-whatsapp)

But it didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass direct data. You should store pdf file in document or temp directory and than pass url of pdf file.

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [storeurl], applicationActivities: [])

self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: ok @iParesh so you are saying `storeurl ` will contain the pdf file..?

Comment: ok..so can u maybe suggest how I can do it..i.e. how do I store my `self.appDelegate.HTMLContent` in `storeUrl`..?

Comment: Here is link may be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503211/create-and-store-pdf-document-programmatically-using-swift-for-ios

Comment: I am storing the pdf file that I created on the code, on NSDocumentDirectory with "NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)" but I cant share the file on whatsapp. It gives a warning like that this type of file cant be shared and closes the activitycontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Use DocumentInteractionController and your issue will be solved

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sample", withExtension: "pdf")!
docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
docController?.delegate = self
docController?.presentOptionsMenu(from: self.view.frame, in:self.view, animated:true)
```

Comment: ok ..so what should there be in place of `self.appDelegate.HTMLContent` ( in my case)

Comment: I had the same issue with activity viewcontroller. When I used documentInteractionController, it worked

Comment: Do u want to share data or url?

Comment: I agree with what u r saying. But where will I place my `pdfData ` in your answer..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171153/discussion-between-suganya-marlin-and-v-bw).