# How to set different parameters in WhatsApp sharing with UIActivityViewController in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController for sharing contents from app.

I want to share different content with different sharing apps.

Like in Message output will be like this.[image + text + URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhJmz.jpg)

in Whatsapp i would like to share like below image [text + URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM0pB.png)

How can i do this? See below screen shots for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share image/text through WhatsApp in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354417/share-image-text-through-whatsapp-in-an-ios-app)

Comment: @SahilKapoor Please check this app : https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/hq-live-trivia-game-show/id1232278996?mt=8 

it is sharing text + URL on whatsapp sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me a good time figuring this out, but that's how it worked for me:

Think of this problem in two steps: first, we need to tell to the UIActivityViewController which content we want to share. Second, we need to return the content based on each social media, either a link, an image or a text. Its up to the social media app to tell which content it can handle, and it will only show up if we share the right kind of content.

In the first step, we will try to fool the social media apps, saying that we want to share an UIImage and a NSObject. This will open most of the social media apps to share.

In the second step, we will identify which social media app the user has clicked, and return the appropriated content for it.

Implementation:

create two UIActivityItemSource, one which will return an UIImage and other which will return the NSObject.

```
class SocialActivityItem: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    var img: UIImage?
    var url: URL?

    convenience init(img: UIImage, url: URL) {
        self.init()
        self.img = img
        self.url = url
    }

    // This will be called BEFORE showing the user the apps to share (first step)
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return img!
    }

    // This will be called AFTER the user has selected an app to share (second step)
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> Any? {
        //Instagram
        if activityType?.rawValue == "com.burbn.instagram.shareextension" {
            return img!
        } else {
            return url
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
class TextActivityItem: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    var textToShare: String?

    convenience init(textToShare: String) {
        self.init()
        self.textToShare = textToShare
    }

    // This will be called BEFORE showing the user the apps to share (first step)
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return NSObject()
    }

    // This will be called AFTER the user has selected an app to share (second step)
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> Any? {
      var text = ""
      if activityType?.rawValue == "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension" {
          text = "Sharing on Whatsapp"
      }

      if activityType == UIActivityType.postToFacebook {
          text = "Sharing on Facebook"
      }
      return text
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to set everything up:

```
let url = URL(string: "www.google.com")!
let socialProvider = SocialActivityItem(img: img, url: url)
let textProvider = TextActivityItem(textToShare: "Sharing on social media!")
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [socialProvider, textProvider], applicationActivities: nil)
```